# curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL with bash shell

Tags: shell, curl

I want to get the random page from wiki and paste it on txt file.

```
curl -I https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random|grep -E "Location:"|cut -d ' ' -f2 > "result.txt"
```

But when I retrieve it from txt file and it come out the error.

```
cat result.txt| xargs -I % curl %
```

Comment: What's the content of your _result.txt_ file? Which shell do you use? Why do you use `xargs -I %`. Have you tried `xargs --verbose`?

Comment: The content show the random url from wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just following redirects with `curl` by adding the `-L` switch? No need to parse the `Location` header:

```
curl -L https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random
```